# Python: logging into a file and also do sys.stdout

Tags: python, python-2.7

I need to write a function that logs into a file (using logging module) and also prints the same content on the console at the same time.

What I have is :

```
def printScreenAndLog(msg):
   log = logging.getLogger()
   log.info(msg)
   now = str(datetime.datetime.now())
   print now,"%s" % msg

def main():
   options, args = usage()
   log = logging.getLogger("CMDR")

   log.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
   fh = logging.FileHandler('cmdr.log')
   fh.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
   formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
   fh.setFormatter(formatter)
   log.addHandler(fh)

   printScreenAndLog("Testing")

if __name__ == "__main__":
   main()
```

Answer (score 1):

This function should do what you require:

```
def configure_logging():
    log_format = '%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s'

    # log to stdout
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG, format=log_format)

    # also log to file
    formatter = logging.Formatter(log_format)
    handler = logging.FileHandler("cmdr.log")
    handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    handler.setFormatter(formatter)
    logging.getLogger('').addHandler(handler)
```

Answer (score 0):

did you try to set the logging level to info instead of debug?
or use log.debug(msg) in your printScreenAndLog function?